# Where does the StatmentId on AWS Lambda function add_permission live?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3

I have created a python (uses boto3 library) script to create an s3 trigger that triggers my lambda function. I first had to add a permission on the lambda that gives s3 lambda:InvokeFunction permission.

```
response = client.add_permission(
    FunctionName='string',
    StatementId='string',
    Action='string',
    Principal='string',
    SourceArn='string')
```

My question is about the StatementId. It says to give a unique Id. If I try to run this again, it complains that this Id already exists.

Where is this StatementId created within Amazon Services? I want to be able to use boto (or cli) to be able to delete and recreate (or update) it so my script is idempotent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `add_permission` method is really adding a statement to the IAM policy associated with your Lambda function.  To view the entire policy, use the `get_policy` method.  This will return the entire policy as a JSON document including any individual statements you have added via `add_permission`.  To remove an individual statement, use `remove_permission` which takes the name of the function and the `statement_id` of the statement to delete, which is why statement_id's have to be unique.

Comment: thanks! Later, I was looking into kappa source code and noticed you use str(uuid.uuid4()) for the statement_id in the add_permission method. I'm kinda humbled that you replied to my question. :)

Answer (score 3):

If encountering this when using Terraform, you can either just omit the statement_id completely, or specify a statement_id_prefix, and TF will generate a unique Id.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_permission